# How to implement video thumbnails like file explorer with electron

Tags: video, ffmpeg, electron, thumbnails

I want to make video thumbnails like file explorer with Electron.

I'm not sure How I can implement this feature.

I've tried with img tag but this is not good solution.

This is because To use img tag I have to get image from video and save it local directory first.

Only after that I can use img tag.

Is there any good way to solve this problem.

Video thumbnails in file explorer

[image]

Comment: If it's just that you don't want to store images into files, you can display base64 encoded images using `img` elements.

Comment: No matter what you will need server side process to extract a thumbnail from the video. You don’t have to store it to disk.